# Hibernate Validator java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957513/exception-in-hibernate-validator-nested-exception-is-java-lang-noclassdeffounde)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764240/nested-exception-is-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-o), but that didn't help...

I am using hibernate validator with the following versions/dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.1.FINAL</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-b08</version>
</dependency>
```

I thought I'm doing everything correctly, and my logs (with verbose:class as a flag) tell me that:

> [Loaded org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl from
>   file:.../hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar]
>
> [Loaded javax.validation.Validation from file:.../validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar]

But later at runtime, when I use

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
```

I get the classic error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl

I also tried downgrading to hibernate-validator 4.3.1 and javax.validation-api 1.0.0, but the error weirdly enough remained the same.

I have loads of other dependencies in this project(e.g. Spring etc.) , but as far as I can see, none that use hibernate-validator or the javax validation api. (If that were the case, I'd also see them loaded in the logs, wouldn't I?)

Is there any help?

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was that Hibernate Validator depended on jboss-logging.
And the jboss logging was not part of my classpath.
The exception was not telling me that the class not def found error while trying to instantiate the hibernate configuration impl was from missing jboss logging on the classpath.

Once I added it to the classpath, the class def not found error went away.

Comment: Good hint.
You should also watch for conflicting dependencies like: jboss-logging and jboss-logging-spi

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue while working with JSR 303 bean validation
I have added below two jar(along with validation-api-1.1.0.final.jar and hibernate-validator-5.0.1.final.jar) and the issue got resolved

1. classmate-0.8.0.jar
   2.jboss-logging-3.1.0.ga.jar

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when working on a spring-boot application. The problem was caused by `hibernate-validator 6.0.11` which seems to have an erroneous dependency on `javax validation-api 2.0.1.Final`. For me the solution was to upgrade to a higher version of hibernate-validator.

In more detail:
My application was depending on `spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.18.RELEASE`. The `spring-boot-starter-web` package depends on `hibernate-validator 6.0.11`, which itself depends on `validation-api-2.0.1.Final`. `validation-api-2.0.1.Final` however requires a higher version of the hibernate validator causing the ValueExtractorManager NoClassDefFoundError.
The problem was fixed after upgrading the application to `spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.18.RELEASE` which utilizes `hibernate-validator 6.0.21.Final`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect multiple implementations of javax.el. That's usually what causes this sort of issues.

Check that you don't have another one with a different name.

If it's not that, add a checkpoint in the ConfigurationImpl constructor and check what's failing.

Comment: That's the thing, it enters the HibernateValidator's `createGenericConfiguration(BootstrapState state)` method, which just has `return new ConfigurationImpl( state );` in it. But fails before it enters the constructor, with the stacktrace being useless... Oh well, I guess I'll have to do without Hibernate Validator...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this config :

```
<properties>

        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies> 
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>    

    </dependencies>
```

For a complete [example](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-and-spring-security-4-integration-example/)..

Answer (score 0):

First, check all dependencies using `mvn dependency:tree` - Find `hibernate-validator` and add below one into pom.xml inside respective dependency - if not required.

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in spring-servelt.xml

```
 <beans:bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"> </beans:bean>
```

and following jars

1. hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar
2. validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar
3. classmate-1.3.4.jar
4. jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar

then all will work fine.

Happy to help...